# get false display result while displaying a csv data into html table

Tags: javascript, html, csv

i have a problem here
i made a page for uploading a csv file and then displaying them into a html table. i have use simple-excel library to do that. 
i have got right value from the csv file but i dont know why. that value not displaying as html table. i have made the method but i think that not work.

somebody please help me with that. the false display result i mean is like this
i give the screenshot of my display
[image]

this my html code and my js for calling them

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

            // check browser support
            // console.log(SimpleExcel.isSupportedBrowser);

            var fileInputCSV = document.getElementById('file'); 


            // when local file loaded
            fileInputCSV.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

                // parse as CSV
                var file = e.target.files[0];
                var csvParser = new SimpleExcel.Parser.CSV();
                csvParser.setDelimiter(',');
                csvParser.loadFile(file, function () {

                    // draw HTML table based on sheet data
                    var sheet = csvParser.getSheet();
                    var table = document.getElementById('result');
                    table.innerHTML = "";
                    sheet.forEach(function (el, i) {                    
                        var row = document.createElement('tr');
                        el.forEach(function (el, i) {
                            var cell = document.createElement('td');
                            cell.innerHTML = el.value;
                            row.appendChild(cell);
                        });
                        table.appendChild(row);
                    });                    

                });
            });



        </script>
```

```html
<div id ="bodi1" style="border:thick; width:100%; height:15%">
<form action="../php/tagihan/tagihan_input.php" id="select1" class="select1" name="select1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table width="50%" style="margin-left:40px">
<p align="center" style="margin-left: 10px"> <strong>Input Data Tagihan Vendor</strong> <br /><br />
 
  <tr>
    <td width="120"  style="border:none"><label style="float:left">Input File</label></td>
    <td width="5"   style="border:none"><label>:</label></td>
    <td width="215" style="border:none"><input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="25" 
    title="Harap check kelengkapan file .csv"/>
    </td>
    <td width="150" style="border:none">
     <img src="../image/ok.png" class="button" name="ok" id="ok" style="height
    :35px; width:40px" />
    <img src="../image/show.png"  class="button" name="dir" id="dir" style="height:35px; width:40px" 
    onclick="up();" />  
    <img src="../image/circle_close_delete_-128.png"  class="button" name="close" id="close" 
    style="height:35px; width:40px"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
<table id="result">
<tr>
</tr>
<td>
</td>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

this the CSV file[image]

Comment: can you share your csv file as well

Comment: how i can share it?

Comment: you can attach an image or simple write the csv values.. 2 lines should do.

Comment: @SrikantSahu i've done that

Answer (score 0):

[image][image]
I have used the js version of Simple-Excel library here.

```
<script src="http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-js/src/simple-excel.js"></script>

<div id="bodi1" style="border: thick; width: 100%; height: 15%">
    <input type="file" id="fileInputCSV">
    <table id="result">
    </table>
</div>

<script>
      // check browser support
      // console.log(SimpleExcel.isSupportedBrowser);
      var fileInputCSV = document.getElementById('fileInputCSV');

      // when local file loaded
      fileInputCSV.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

          // parse as CSV
          var file = e.target.files[0];
          var csvParser = new SimpleExcel.Parser.CSV();
          csvParser.setDelimiter(',');
          csvParser.loadFile(file, function () {

              // draw HTML table based on sheet data
              var sheet = csvParser.getSheet();
              var table = document.getElementById('result');
              table.innerHTML = "";
              sheet.forEach(function (el, i) {
                  var row = document.createElement('tr');
                  el.forEach(function (el, i) {
                      var cell = document.createElement('td');
                      cell.innerHTML = el.value;
                      row.appendChild(cell);
                  });
                  table.appendChild(row);
              });
          });
      });
</script>
```

Please arrange these code blocks accordingly in your file. The second script tag should go as the last tag inside body tag.

Comment: how you set the csv file? 
you give that csv a border or not?

Comment: or my excel file format not as 2003 file ?
i use excel 2007

Comment: It does not matter... you can write the csv file in a notepad and save it in .csv format. Remove the blank lines form your csv file and try again... I have used Excel 2016 but that does not impact anything.

Comment: still same T_T.. it give `;` as the separator not form a table